# How does this animation work - website logo fades to smaller version on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

On this site - http://fkplaw.com/ if you scroll down the main logo changes size.

I can see in the JS where the classes are changed to switch images from large to small but I cannot figure out how the logo tweens so smoothly from large to small...?

Comment: its a css animation, triggered by changing the class.

Comment: Look at the CSS. They're using [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. As it is now, this question is off topic

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @MikeC I saw your comment, thanks for that

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/q5qca8om/3/

Comment: They are changing the `background-image` and the `height` of logo when `.large` class is added and removed and also the transition is set to all so changing background image and height would happen in a smooth way!

Comment: @Paulie_D Cheers for the heads up. But isn't the issue here that I didn't actually know what code was creating this, so in theory I'd have to copy the entire site :/